# Regarding the force acting on a small patch on the the surface of a charged sphere

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

In Purcell's Electricity and Magnetism, page 30 and 31, there is a section which dealt with the evaluation of the force acting on a small patch (the tiny square in the picture) on a charged sphere:

[image]

Here's how he began his reasoning:

> Consider, separately, the force on *dq*  due to all the other charges in the distribution, and the force on the patch due to the charges within the patch itself. 
>   This latter force is surely zero. Coulomb repulsion between charges 
>   within the patch is just another example of Newton's third law; the 
>   patch as a whole cannot push on itself. That simplifies our problem, 
>   for it allows us to use the entire electric field E, **including the field due 
>   to all charges in the patch**, in calculating the force dF on the patch of 
>   charge dq:
>   $$dF = E \times dq = E \times \sigma dA$$

So according to the author:

The patch doesn't exert a force on itself $\implies$ We can **include the electric field generated by the patch itself** in the total $E$ field, which is used above to compute $dF$.

How would you justify the implication above?

P.S. $\sigma$ is the uniform surface charge density on the sphere.
*dq*  refers to the charge of the small patch in the picture above, and equals $\sigma$dA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was too long to fit in the comment section; What should be obvious, but maybe isn't, is that the electric field directly above and below the patch is equal to the vector sum of the electric field generated by the patch, the electric field generated by the rest of the conductor, and the external electric field. In this case, the electric field below the surface is equal to zero and the electric field above the surface is directly determined by the boundary condition for the electric field at the surface. And since the patch cannot exert a force on itself, the electric force exerted on it is entirely due to the remaining electric field. So b/c it's zero you don't need to add it or subtract it out as some may think.

Comment: So if I understood correctly, the electric field right above the patch is entirely due to the charge distributed over the surface other than the patch itself, i.e.,  the sphere minus the small patch, correct?

Comment: yes. you could visually consider the tiny patch removed.

Comment: But then, the removal of the patch would obviously remove the field geberated by the patch, thus making the overall field less than E, this is in contradiction with what the author said. We cannot just remove the patch and disregard the field generated by it.

Comment: The assumption is that the patch is infinitesimally small and the height above it infinitesimally small. With that assumption, it is okay to proceed.

Comment: http://physicspages.com/pdf/Griffiths%20EM/Griffiths%20Problems%2002.37-38.pdf

Comment: There's an inconsistency in the linked document, the author said that we made two assumptions: **1.** We consider the patch to be small enough so that it could be considered as a point charge.
 **2.** We position ourselves close enough to the patch so that the field above it equals $\sigma /2\epsilon_{0}$. 
We clearly cannot have both assumptions at once, for if the second assumption holds, we would be so close to the patch that we could no longer regard it as a point charge, which the first assumption presupposes.

Comment: Maybe I do not properly understand this. I was under the belief the distance didn't break the first assumption.